# How do I get a output into a tkinter Entry field

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, tkinter, output

Im making my own cypher encryption and I want to put the result into the entry field called output. Now im just using print() so I could test if I got a result. But that was only for testing. This is one of the first times I used Python so if there are some other things I could have done better please let me know :)
this is what I have so far.

```
from tkinter import *

#Make frame
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")
root.title("Encryption Tool")

top_frame = Frame(root)
bottom_frame = Frame(root)

top_frame.pack()
bottom_frame.pack()

#Text
headline = Label(top_frame, text="Encryption Tool", fg='black')
headline.config(font=('Courier', 27))
headline.grid(padx=10, pady=10)

Key = Label(bottom_frame, text="Key:", fg='black')
Key.config(font=('Courier', 20))
Key.grid(row=1)

Text_entry = Label(bottom_frame, text="Text:", fg='black')
Text_entry.config(font=('Courier', 20))
Text_entry.grid(row=2)

Output_text = Label(bottom_frame, text="Output:", fg='black')
Output_text.config(font=('Courier', 20))
Output_text.grid(row=3)

Key_entry = Entry(bottom_frame)
Key_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

Text_entry = Entry(bottom_frame)
Text_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

Output_text = Entry(bottom_frame)
Output_text.grid(row=3, column=1)

#Encryption_button

def encrypt():
    result = ''
    text = ''

    key = Key_entry.get()
    text = Text_entry.get()
    formule = int(key)

    for i in range(0, len(text)):
            result = result + chr(ord(text[i]) + formule + i * i)


    result = ''                                     

Encryption_button = Button(bottom_frame, text="Encrypt", fg='black')
Encryption_button.config(height = 2, width = 15)
Encryption_button.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = S)
Encryption_button['command'] = encrypt


#Decryption_button

def decrypt():
    result = ''
    text = ''

    key = Key_entry.get()
    text = Text_entry.get()
    formule = int(key)

    for i in range(0, len(text)):
            result = result + chr(ord(text[i]) - formule - i * i)

    print(result)
    result = ''

Decryption_button = Button(bottom_frame, text="Decrypt", fg="black")
Decryption_button.config(height = 2, width = 15)
Decryption_button.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = S)
Decryption_button['command'] = decrypt

#Quit_button
def end():
    exit()

Quit_button = Button(bottom_frame, text="Quit", fg='black')
Quit_button.config(height = 2, width = 15)
Quit_button.grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = S)

Quit_button['command'] = end

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you using an `Entry` widget for output? Seems like a [`Text`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190406031334id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text.html) widget would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way to do this with tkinter would be with a StringVar() object you can connect to the Entry object (Some [documentation](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) here).

```
output_entry_value = StringVar()

Output_text = Entry(bottom_frame, textvariable=output_entry_value)
Output_text.grid(row=3, column=1)
```

then you can .set() the result in the stringvar, and it will update in the entries you connected it to:

```
output_entry_value.set(result)
```